# Java Spring Rest API. Returning referenced objects or object's ids?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am implementing simple social media api. Each `Post` object has a field `userId` - identifier which can be used to pull `User` object (author of the post) from database.

When client application asks for some post should I give back `Post` object as is and provide a way to retrieve `User` for and given `userid` or prepare an object that already contains full user object?

variant 1:

`{"content":"cool post",userId:1}`

variant 2:

`{"content":"cool post","user": {"name":"Mike"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on, for example, how you expect your clients to use the data. Are most clients going to use all `User` details, or will most clients be interested in only the `content` field?

If you want to provide more flexibility to the clients, consider adding a field, say `isFullUserInfoNeeded`, in request params. Depending on whether it is set to `true` or not, you can respond with full `User` details or just the `userId`.